# creating thread or parallel programming for multiple dropdown boxes populated by SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

So I have a poco class with extension method that populates a select list as shown below. Suppose I have 10 dropdown boxes and each extension method goes to the database and populates the SelectList.
Now I want to start each method as a thread is this a good idea.... I am seeking for advice and things that would be better to increase performance and speed.  Is the thread more expensive than a sql connection? Should I run two processes per thread ,three, four...?

```
class person
{
  public person()
  { 
   CrimesListbox1      = CrimesListBox1.populate();
   CrimesListBox2      = CrimesListBox1.populate();
   CrimesListBox3      = CrimesListBox1.populate();
    //so instead of the above way should i..... do the following? 


   Thread t = new Thread (this.CrimesListBox1.populate());          // Kick off a new thread
   t.Start();
   Thread t2 = new Thread (this.CrimesListBox2.populate());   
   t2.Start();
  }
    public SelectList CrimesListBox1{get;set}
    public SelectList CrimesListBox2{get;set}



    public static SelectList populate(this SelectList Object)
        {
                CrimesDataContext LinqCtx = new CrimesDataContext ();

                var CrimesListBox1=
                       (
                        from x in LinqCtx.CrimesListBox1
                        orderby x.Crimes
                        select x
                       );
                Object= 
                        new SelectList
                        (
                            CrimesListBox1, "CrimeId", "CrimeName"
                        );
                return Object;
            }
}//end of the person class
```

Comment: have you already measured that it is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to start each method as a thread is this a good idea....

No. It is an idea starting with "S" and ending with "D" and having 4 letters.

Threads have overhead. Lets get into the points:

- It may make little sense really to use async programming of any form - simply not going to result in avisible difference unltess the boxes are long.
- if they are, though, there may bea benefit. But using separate threads is bordering not knowing the .NET framework.

Solution:

- For current .NET use TASKS. The Tasks framework is done for exactly that.
- For .NET 4.5 use async methods.

Those use internally boh a thread POOL, so they do not open another thread for every small request, but keep a pool of worker threads whih get assigned those small tasks. Because creating and destroying the thread has a nontrivial overhead. The ThreadPool (pre .net 4.0 solution), the tasks framework and the async methods in the next version where made exaxctly for NOT having to deal with those items. Tasks are good enough and available now.

Comment: After reading your comments I found this:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C and it was very usefull. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using threading for this purpose is a bad idea. Consider this rule of thumb. Don't use threading when competing for the same resource. A resource can be disk, db, screen, user interface. Your db does not get faster when using threading, because the amount of work of work is the same on the same resource.

Just like computing a cpu heavy calculation on a single core will not be faster by splitting the work using threading. Just like reading a number of files from a single disk will not be faster by splitting the work with threading.

These examples use a single resource, cpu and disk, which is working as fast as it can.

Threading is useful when you want to combine two resources. Reading from disk while performing cpu calculation, threading can be a benefit to prefetch data for the calculation etc.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however the biggest problem with his idea is not perf as you suggest, but the enormous increase in complexity without demonstrating an increase in perf (even if he did it the right way using Task<T>. It's possible (unlikely) that doing these calls in parallel results in less ET. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use Parallel Linq(PLinq) if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Sadly that is pretty exactly NOT what PLinq has beeen created for. Because every of the 10 drop downs will run a DIFFERENT operation.

Comment: Sunil - you have made a guess, rather than provided an answer. And an incorrect guess at that. Please do not guess as it makes it more difficult to find useful advice on the page. Consider focusing your attention on answering questions that are within your expertise.